# Angular: Cannot return custom error message via HttpResponse

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular-http-interceptors, asp.net-core-middleware

I've been googling the workaround and seen examples when we return error text in *controller action* as `ActionResult`/`JsonResult` or using `HttpRequest` approach as follows

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "error text";
```

For my back-end app I use `ASP.NET Core 2.1.1` and `.Status` property is missing in `HttpResponse` class.

Moreover I can't find any properties which could contain my custom error message.

I use middleware class which grabs exception description and passes it as `JSON`

`Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandleMiddleware>();
```

The class itself

```
public class ExceptionHandleMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ExceptionHandleMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = $"{ex.GetType().FullName}: '{ex.Message}'" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the line

```
context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
```

This is required because in my **Angular 6 app** I use `HttpInterceptor`, and in order to catch error you're supposed to return an HTTP error (otherwise the `.catch(...)` block isn't being triggered in Angular interceptor).

Here's the bit from my Angular app

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private notify: NgNotify,
    ) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next
            .handle(req)
            .catch(this.handleError)
    }
    ...
```

Although `context.Response.WriteAsync(...)` bit **does return** the exception text, I am unable to extract it in `.catch(...)` block of the interceptor.

```
public handleError = (error: Response) => {
```

Here's `error` printed as `JSON` (note that it's lacking the error message saying *"Last Entry"*)

```
{  
    "headers":{  
       "normalizedNames":{  

       },
       "lazyUpdate":null
    },
    "status":500,
    "statusText":"OK",
    "url":"https://localhost:44305/api/Entry/GetNext?id=11962",
    "ok":false,
    "name":"HttpErrorResponse",
    "message":"Http failure response for https://localhost:44305/api/Entry/GetNext?id=11962: 500 OK",
    "error":{  

    }
 }
```

Nevertheless, if I open chrome's *Network* tab I can see the following

[image]

So, I can't seem to fetch this error text from `error: Response`.

Perhaps, someone knows a better way of passing error to Angular client and fetching it there?

**Update 1 - error handler** (I've only put the breakpoint there in order to investigate the error's content)

```
public handleError = (error: Response) => {
    debugger
    return Observable.throw(error)
}
```

Comment: Can you show your error handler? Normally, with `error.error` you should be able to get the body

Comment: Are you sure the request has the required `status` code? I could not see the request in red colour which could signify that it failed. Please check the status code in Chrome's network tab.

Comment: certainly @David , but for now it is almost lacking any code. I'm now looking into `error.body.getReader().read().then(...)` part (...have just discovered it)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `Response` is from the old Http client, isn't it?  Have a look there, it might help https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

Comment: @David on the page you've provided there's `HttpErrorResponse` - it doesn't work with Angular 6, this one (`Response`) seems to be new, and the interface itself is found in lib.dom.d.ts.

Comment: OK. So if you do a console.log from error.error, what do you get?

Comment: @David yes, you can find that part in my post - `error` is just an empty object.

Comment: @David also https://i.imgur.com/CjuJrwB.png

Comment: From the screenshot, it's not empty. It's says a blob, with a size

Comment: @David ah exactly! Will be looking into it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My oversight.

If you look at the JSON returned

```
  ....

  "message":"Http failure response for https://localhost:44305/api/Entry/GetNext?id=11962: 500 OK",
  "error":{  

  }
}
```

`error` seems to be an **empty object**

IN FACT `error` is a `Blob` which we are supposed to read in the following way

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
        .handle(req)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}

public handleError = (error: Response) => {

    let reader = new FileReader();

    let ngNotify = this._ngNotify;

    reader.onload = function () {

        var result = JSON.parse(this.result);

        ngNotify.nofity('Error', result.error);
    };

    reader.readAsText(error['error']);

    return Observable.throw(error)
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: I have this same issue.  Using ASP NET CORE with middleware that sets error body like `await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);` where result is some json.  Seems I have issue on the Angular client side to consume the error:  `error = { }`. Did you ever refine this or find a more Angular way?  I am using v7.x

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solve this by implementing middle-ware to intercept the `HttpResponse`, extract error from blob, and return the message in the json.  Thanks to [JaapMosselman's contribution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19888#issuecomment-349650709).